# Issues running Civ 6 through Nvidia Graphics card on Laptop - Ubuntu 16.04 Lts

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

Essentially Civ 6 is only giving me the option to run through integrated graphics.
I have an Nvidia GeForce 750M graphics card and have properly downloaded the recommended driver (Nvidia-381).
I also have access to Prime profiles and it is set to my Nvidia card.

However the command:

```
lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
```

shows:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Dell Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

As you can see my Nvidea GPU is not even being identified, any help on this would be great :)

Edit: I ran the command with "3d" and as you said it did work thanks.

If that's the case and it's running the game through Nvidia but simply not showing that in the in game-options is there a way to verify that?

[The drop-down is only showing Intel graphics as an option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D17t0.jpg)

Edit 2: ran some benchmarks and downloaded a program to monitor GPU-CPU etc. And when running Civ 6  the GPU is running at max in graphics & the benchmarks are too good for Intel graphics
So I can only assume with Ubuntu not being able to switch between the 2 Civ 6 can only show 1 option regardless of which graphics drive it uses. And it defaults to integrated as the shown option.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: With "VGA" that's the expected result. Try "3D" instead. And if Nvidia is selected then you're using Nvidia. Please edit and explain exactly what the problem is, if any. I would guess you actually don't have any problem simply because the game wouldn't run if you were using the integrated graphics.

Comment: Fwiw, I am having the same issue/quirk, but my card is also being used, it just isn't detected in Civ. (For whoever may see this is the future.)

Comment: What program did you use to test this? I have the same issue. Could you maybe post an answer with your approach?